# Simplest HTTP/TCP switcher

Tags: http, tcp, switching

I have two tomcat instances running on ports A and B. I would like all traffic on port C to be forward to A or B, ideally with a simple command and minimal configuration.

Is there a simple TCP switcher that can change the traffic like that ?

UPDATE: changing from ports A to B manually (command line for example) would be ok.

Comment: Randomly? Evenly? How should the choice be made where it goes?

Comment: DNS round robin ? Or do you want to monitor the state of Tomcat and need the features of a Loadbalancer with Apache, nginx or other solution ? Which OS do you use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iptables` offer the `PREROUTING` specifier for that:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport <C> -j REDIRECT --to-port <A>
```

Here `<C>` and `<A>` obviously refer to your ports.

Comment: Perhaps I dont understand your solution: where do you take care of B ?

Comment: @Marged I don't. The OP asked for "a simple command" to switch. I assume he is happy with one command to switch to `A` and one command to switch to `B`. Maybe by creating `aliases`. There is no mentioning of some automatic scheme or similar in the question.

Comment: Thanks for clarification